# set diffrent virtualhost DocumentRoot for specific urls under the same domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a project under domain like example.com  and i defined a virtualhost for it and it's working fine, i just want to server example.com/about from fully different DocumentRoot

I tried to configure ProxyPass but it's only serve the request but all page assets files (css,js ,etc ) are served from the other DocumentRoot.

I tried also rewrite rule but it's giving 403!

Example of the two projects path

Project1 /var/www/project1
Project2 /var/www/project2

How i want it to work

http://example.com/ => server the url and all it's assets from  /var/www/project1

http://example.com/any-page => server the url and all it's assets from  /var/www/project1

http://example.com/about => server the url and all it's assets from  /var/www/project2

Comment: Show your Virtual Hosts definition file `httpd-vhost.conf` I am guessing you have done something wrong

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html) in your `.htaccess` or virtual host config file.

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/project1
Alias /any-page /var/www/project1
Alias /about /var/www/project2
```

You will not need the alias for `/any-page` if project1 already has a directory with that name. If it doesn't then going to `/any-page` will be identical to going to `/`